# Tensorflow model wont train when using validation data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning-model

Im trying to train a tensorflow neural network. Since the training data is too big for my computer RAM I have divided it into sub-datsets and sequentially use them for training. I have a problem however, if I call model.fit with the validation_data parameter the code returns an error. If i do not pass any validation data I works perfectly.

```
epochs = 30
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test = read_val(3, val_ratio=0.5)
print("start training")
for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("\n" + str(epoch))
        for n in range(3):
            x_t, y_t = read_small(n)
            history = model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
            x_t = []; y_t = [];
```

The `read_small(n)` essentially reads the sub-dataset for the training data. If call the function as: `history = model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=0)` the full training is accomplished for the 30 epocs and no error is returned.

However if I call the function as given in the code: `history = model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))` the program returns the following error:

*"C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\CVISEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype) numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 477. MiB for an array with shape (125000, 1000) and data type float32*

But the error happens at around epoch number 15, so it's not like the computer lacks RAM to read the validation data.

I have tried dividing the training data into smaller datasets and it does not help. I also tried to only call `model.fit` with the validation parameter once every n epochs and it still ends up returning the error.

What could be the problem? Does `model.fit` generate a copy of the validation data every time the function is called even though I already read them before?